# How to order by count of related entity

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-order-by, hql

I have two entities, File and Commentary:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FILE")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@XmlRootElement
public class File implements Serializable {

    (...)
    private Set<Commentary> commentaries = new HashSet<Commentary>();

    (...)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "file")
    public Set<Commentary> getCommentaries() {
        return commentaries;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMENTARY")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Commentary implements Serializable {

(...)
private File file;

(...)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "FILE_ID")
public File getFile() {
    return file;
}
```

I want to make a HQL query to get Files, ordering them by the number of commentaries each one has associated. I tried:

```
SELECT f FROM FILE f WHERE f.name LIKE '%example%' ORDER BY COUNT(f.commentaries)
```

with no luck. How can I do this properly using HQL?

Comment: What error are you observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Correct HQL query is:

```
SELECT f FROM FILE f WHERE f.name LIKE '%example%' ORDER BY size(f.commentaries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT f FROM FILE f WHERE f.name LIKE '%example%' ORDER BY COUNT(commentaries)
```